# Use ng-click to toggle checkboxes by altering <i> element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, material-design

I have a list of checkboxes generated using material design using the MUI CSS framework, the code below basically basically loops through an array and display 5 checkboxes.

The `<i>` tag contains either 'check_box' OR 'check_box_outline_blank' - if it shows 'check_box' this "checkbox" appears ticked, if it contains 'check_box_outline_blank' it will show the "checkbox" appearing as unticked.

Using ng-click I want to utilise the function toggleNetwork to basically toggle the `<i>` tag to contain either 'check_box' OR 'check_box_outline_blank'

// HTML

```
<div class="detail permissions" ng-class="{unfolded: role.showDetails != 'permissions'}" border-watch>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="page in rule.pages" ng-click="toggleNetwork(this); ruleForm.$setDirty()">
      <span class="pull-left"><i class="check material-icons nomargin ">check_box</i></span>
      <i class="icon icon-{{page.service}}"></i>
      <span class="permission-description">{{page.name}}</span>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

// Javascript

```
$scope.toggleNetwork = function(this) {
  // change the `<i>` element to either 'check_box' OR 'check_box_outline_blank'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try

```
<i class="material-icons show-icon" ng-if="!clicked">check_box_outline_blank</i>
<i class="material-icons show-icon" ng-if="clicked">check_box</i>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LrSRwq6IaeFauJzbCjd?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

the simples way to do something like that:
in controller:

```
create $scope.isChecked = false;
$scope.toggleNetwork = function(isChecked) {
  isChecked = !isChecked;
}
```

in html element:

```
<li ng-click="toggleNetwork(isChecked)">
   <i>{{isChecked ? 'check_box' : 'check_box_outline_blank'}}</i>
</li>
```